# Which of the five main branches of chemistry has the most labwork?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Budding chemistry student here.

I am aware of the so called "five branches" of chemistry, namely organic, inorganic, bio, physical and analytical.

Which of these paths lead to work with the most lab time?

I suspect physical chemistry would be fairly academic, considering it's links to physics and maths. Which is also very appealing.

Comment: Physical chemistry also involves lab work such as titrations , preparation of various acids, bases, salts etc

Comment: Lab work in actual phys chem research is not the same as student lab experiments designed to illustrate concepts in phys chem.

Comment: Are we talking about lab work for your thesis, or lab work in an academic position or in industry? Also, are these categories relevant any more in research?

Comment: Analytical is not usually a separate branch. Used to be, when analytics were still largely actual lab chemistry with solvents and pipettes and bunsen burners.

Comment: The only way to spend your complete graduate studies in front of a computer is doing it in theoretical chemistry, i.e. QM and simulation.

Comment: Personally I am in an interdisciplinary field and I have direct or indirect experience with many techniques and type of lab work. I have no doubt that the field requiring most *physical presence and work at the bench* is organic synthesis. No idea about biochemistry, tough. And though I am categorical, everything need work. There are experiment in which you wait hours, but need to be there at 22 pm, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

All the five so-called branches of chemistry require heavy use of the brain. Modern chemistry is very interdisciplinary. At the research level, the distinction among these branches becomes blurry. Everyone is doing some part of each branch. Traditional inorganic and organic chemistry both require a lot of wet work and synthesis and characterization.
If you ask which branch of chemistry has the highest level of automation, and most of the work is done by instruments-it is analytical chemistry. Many modern physical chemists or theoretical chemists rely on *in silico* techniques (=computers, modelling, simulations etc). You may not be doing a single real experiment (if your not lucky). Computer is your virtual lab. As a hardcore theoretical chemist, finding a job afterwards in the field, may be difficult. My acquaintance switched to computer programming after a PhD, which was a wise decision after remaining jobless for a year. He learned programming languages in the mean time. In any case, all fields are good. It all depends on your passion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

There are a LOT more branches and sub-branches of Chemistry than you mentioned. Under inorganic chemistry alone, we have the chemistry of the main groups, as well as transition metal chemistry (and organometallic chemistry) as well as f-block chemistry. Owing to the interdisciplinary nature of modern Chemistry (some call MOT/VBT "The theory underlying all fields of chemistry", and rightly so) its impossible to say "I'm an inorganic chemist and I never deal with organic chemistry" or something along those lines.

There's also, as mentioned, the rise of computational methods like the Density Functional method (DFT) and "in silico" (literally "in silicon", i.e. using a computer) methods are also quite popular, and there are research papers with titles like "DFT analysis of [title]". If you want to go into the field of quantum/computational chemistry, you probably don't need much lab work (which is something I personally despise).

Hope this helped.